# LinieSeries Color Binding not work oxyPlot

Tags: wpf, colors, binding, oxyplot

I'm trying to bind the `LineSeries` `Color` to my viewmodel. It has no effect.
What is wrong?

The Datacontext is set in the MainWindow. That works because I get the data from Chartpoints.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyLayerThicknessApp.UserControls.RefAufnehmenEdit"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLayerThicknessApp.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="850" d:DesignWidth="1000">
    <Grid>
            <!--Chart-->
                <oxy:Plot 
                      LegendOrientation="Vertical"
                      LegendPlacement="Outside"
                      LegendPosition="RightTop" Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="False">
                    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
                        <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Bottom" Minimum="400" Maximum="850"  MajorGridlineStyle="None" MinorGridlineStyle="None" Title="Wellenlänge [nm]" />
                <oxy:LinearAxis Position="Left" Minimum="0" Maximum="4000" Title="Intensität" MajorStep="1000" MajorGridlineStyle="Automatic" MinorGridlineStyle="None"/>
            </oxy:Plot.Axes>
                    <oxy:Plot.Series>
                        <oxy:LineSeries 

                                       DataFieldY="YValue" DataFieldX="XValue" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartPoints}" Color="{Binding LinieColor}" LineStyle="Solid" />
                    </oxy:Plot.Series>
                </oxy:Plot>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

// Mainwindow
<Window x:Class="MyLayerThicknessApp.Views.RecipesView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyLayerThicknessApp.Views"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyLayerThicknessApp.ViewModels"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Wpf;assembly=OxyPlot.Wpf"    
        xmlns:MyControls="clr-namespace:MyLayerThicknessApp.UserControls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="RezepteWindow" Height="850" Width="1200" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" Style="{StaticResource Window}" IsEnabled="{Binding MainWindowIsEnable}"  >
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:RecipesViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>


                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <MyControls:RefAufnehmenEdit Visibility="{Binding VisEditRefAufnehmen, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"  />
                </Grid>

</Window>
```

My ViewModel. I also try with Color and Brushes. Nothing works.
The INotifyPropertyChanged is in the MainViewMode. This works for sure.

```
public class RecipesViewModel : MainViewModel
{
    private bool visEditRefAufnehmen;
    public bool VisEditRefAufnehmen
    {
        get { return visEditRefAufnehmen; }
        set
        {
            if (visEditRefAufnehmen != value)
            {
                visEditRefAufnehmen = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged("VisEditRefAufnehmen");  // To notify when the property is changed
            }
        }
    }

    private OxyColor linieColor = OxyColor.Parse("255,0,0");
    public OxyColor LinieColor
    {
        get { return linieColor; }
        set
        {
            if (linieColor != value)
            {
                linieColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("LinieColor");  // To notify when the property is changed
            }
        }
    }

    private List<DataPoint> currentchartPoints;
    public List<DataPoint> CurrentchartPoints
    {
        get { return currentchartPoints; }
        set
        {
            if (value != currentchartPoints)
            {
                currentchartPoints = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CurrentchartPoints");
            }
        }
    }

    private void spektrumAufnehmen()
    {
        if (spektrometer == null)
        {
            spektrometer = MySpektrometer.getInstanz();
            spektrometer.SetINtegrationTime(10);
        }

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (VisEditRefAufnehmen)
            {
                double[] intensity = MySpektrometer.Wrapper.getSpectrum(0);
                double[] wave = MySpektrometer.Wrapper.getWavelengths(0);

                wave = MyFilter.convertBigArrayToSmall(wave, intensity, Brechungsindex.WAVELENGTHAREA);
                ChartPoints = DoubleArrayToChartPoints(wave);
            }
        });

    }
}
// INotifyPropertyChanged
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: First of all, you should check if LinieColor getter is called by the view. You can start the app into debug mode, place a breakpoint on the line get { return linieColor; }, and see if the debugger stops there or not. Let me know.

Comment: The debugger stops there.

Comment: Ok, then the viewmodel is correcly set. We need more code to debug this. Post the entire xaml + xaml.cs and viewmodel if possible.

Comment: The whole code is too long. But that should be the relevant part. Xaml.cs is empty

Comment: On the LineSeries you have ItemsSource="{Binding ChartPoints}", while in the viewmodel the property is called CurrentchartPoints.

Comment: Also, the issue is with the color (meaning the line is shown but with a different color) or with the series (does the series show at all)?

Comment: Yes Chartpoints works but the linie Color is green. They should be red.

Comment: Try with OxyColor.Parse("#FF0000")

Comment: This also not work. I tryed  to change the color in the while loop with LinieColor = OxyColor.Parse("255,0,0"); The OnPropertyChanged("LinieColor"); doesen`t fired.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't fire? The debugger should pass there. Also, immediately after you call OnPropertyChanged, it should pass at the getter of LinieColor. Does it do that?

Comment: Yes, but only at the start onetime.

Comment: When you set the LinieColor in the while loop, is the getter of LinieColor called?

Comment: No is not called.

Comment: Can i see the OnPropertyChanged method?

Comment: I added to the post. I am sure they work.

Comment: Running out of ideas :) One thing i see is you're updating ChartPoints from a Task.Run. Can you try, just for debugging purposes, to try running it without the Task.Run, so that it runs on the UI thread.

Comment: Without task also no effekt to the color. Thanks for your time. Also running out of ideas.

Comment: If you want, upload the solution on github and i'll try to debug it to see where's the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property [LineSeries.Color](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/Source/OxyPlot.Wpf/Series/Series.cs) expects a type of `System.Windows.Media.Color`, where as, the the property in your ViewModel, `LinieColor`, is of type `OxyColor`.

**From OxyPlot Source**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Color", typeof(Color), typeof(Series), new PropertyMetadata(MoreColors.Automatic, AppearanceChanged));
```

**From your ViewModel**

```
public OxyColor LinieColor
```

You could resolve the binding issue by using a converter that converts `OxyColor` to `Color`. A simplest converter for the purpose could be following.

```
public class OxyColorToColorConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is OxyColor color)
                return color.ToColor();

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And in your XAML

```
<oxy:LineSeries DataFieldY="YValue" DataFieldX="XValue" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartPoints}" Color="{Binding LinieColor,Converter={StaticResource OxyColorToColorConverter}}" LineStyle="Solid" />
```